# mPDF load issue - infine load & 500 error

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to use PHP+MYSQL to generate PDF with mPDF library, it works for small files under 100kb, but over 500KB files are just infinitely loading on browser and after some time giving 500 error, can you please tell me what to do to optimize the server and script for this to work.

Using:
Type: VPS
Server: xeon e5 2620
RAM: 8GB
Core: 2 (Dedicated)

Note: In earlier VPS it was working without any problem. But don't know what problem is with it now. On average the file sizes are also less than 800kb.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I can help. Maybe you should display the variable before calling pdf convert and see if there are something wrong with that

```
include_once('pdf.class.php');
include_once('file.class.php');

$pdf=new pdf;

$content='content here';

echo $content;

//$pdf->html=$content;

//$pdf->Cria();
```